# multiple domain session handling in servlets

Tags: javascript, tomcat, multiple-domains

I need to share sessions between multiple domains.

By multiple domain I mean, I have one instance of tomcat6 running. And I can access my webapp using urls
localhost:8080/webapp/test.jsp  and
myhostname:8080/webapp/test.jsp  (as I configured dns entry in hosts file)

Now,
The javascript fires ajax calls to localhost:8080/webapp/ActionA  and myhostname:8080/webapp/ActionB

Now it will throw an error for the invalid session.

If javascript fires ajax calls to localhost:8080/webapp/ActionA  and localhost:8080/webapp/ActionB  it will work fine.

Can some one suggest some ways to implement this.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a proper Single sign-on implementaion. 
Try one of the [OpenId providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) like Google, Yahoo, MSN